# Unable to run internet in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10

I have MTS MBlaze working fine till Ubuntu 12.04.
But now I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 on the same desktop, but it doesn't work
Why?

Comment: have u configured it properly? I mean setup a new mobile broadband connection?

Answer (score 0):

```
Ping 8.8.8.8
```

If this ping is successfull, then check /etc/resolv.conf if this contains 127.0.0.1 please use following code to fix this partially as you need to run this code every time you change network.

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
sudo dhclient $connectionname #mobileBroadband in your case
```

This will set you DNS Server to what you ISP provides, Alternatively you can try

```
vi /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

and edit the above file with Google public DNS (8.8.8.8) or Open DNS(208.67.222.222)
and check again.

Comment: ping 8.8.8.8
Connect: Network is unreachable

Comment: cat /etc/resolv.conf=# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

Comment: once resolv.conf printed=nameserver 127.0.1.1 and not 127.0.0.1

Comment: If you can't reach 8.8.8.8 then your internet connection is not working try re-installing you mBlaze again, there is a bug in 12.10 our changes in /etc/resolv.conf are not getting overwritten therefore even with the active internet connection We are not able to browse.

Comment: I deleted MBlaze and reinstalled, but no effect.